# How to achieve encapsulation in C++ with getter method

Tags: c++, oop

In below code, I am assigning the value to url from another class function.
I have received code review comment that 'Make url as private and 
implement getter function which should return the `std::string` 
value via an output parameter passed by reference'

```
class http_client
{
    public:
        std::string url;
};
```

I am confused with the above comment because I am using url only to set a value outside of http_client class. Initially, I thought that I have to make 
one public setter method which will set the value to url as shown in below.

```
class http_client
{
    private:
        std::string url;
    public:
        void set_url(const std::string& url)
        {
            this->url = url;
        }
};
```

Can anyone suggest what I am missing with above code review comment?

Comment: Your reviewer seems to be a fan of Java beans

Comment: The encapsulation would be overhead only if `url` just holds data without any side effect. (Even in this case encapsulation could be a matter of unique style.) In common case, members mostly have a side effect. Hence, they are usually made `private `and the setter (the exlusive method to change the member) is responsible to grant this side effect when the member is changed. Now, the getter is necessary to simply access (read) the member. Making it `inline`, the access via function will cause no overhead in (optimized) code.

Comment: I disagree with your reviewer. Out parameters are bad taste, error prone and unnecessary.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does Java beans uses the same approach for encapsulation?

Comment: @myuu - Yes. Getters and setters all over the place, for simple aggregates.

Comment: @Scheff so why does many peoples used to set value via getter method?

Comment: @JesperJuhl So, my Initial thought was right? To use setter function?

Comment: If a a getter provides a non-const reference to member which can be used for direct access... then this getter/setter thing becomes somehow useless, does it? This leaves the only weak argument of "matter of style". _so why does many peoples used to set value via getter method?_ I don't know. Either I missed something or those people just write bad code (or at least code I don't like). ;-)

Comment: I agree with @JesperJuhl: what you're being asked to do is a poor idea, and you should push back against that code review. I'd go a bit further though: I'd recommend that the url be represented by a class itself. That class should know about things like how to validate a url and how to do url encoding, possibly how to create a url from a server name, port, path, parameters, etc., and possibly also take a complete url apart into the same pieces. Then the http client should contain an instance of that class, rather than an `std::string`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin We are 100% sure that we are getting correct url generated by another class object.

Comment: @myuu Java Beans uses the getter/setter approach for determining which properties should be visible or modifiable through GUI tools. If I remember my history, this was the sanest approach you could implement in Java at the time (~20 years ago). Unfortunately, many people learned about this, didn't understand the purpose, and thus the "getter/setters everywhere" encapsulation-breaking plague was upon us.

Comment: You need to ask your commenter for clarification, as the comment is unrelated to setting the value.

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks, that's the actual root cause of  "getter/setters everywhere".

Comment: Another reason given for getters is the ability to later change the implementation without the changing the interface. This applies when the first implementation is to store the value as a member, but possibly in the future we might calculate a value on demand or get the value from some other location. With a setter we can make the change without changing calls to the setter, with direct access to the member it would be a breaking change. Sometimes this is a decent enough argument, but sometimes - maybe when it's a simple data object - it's just not ever going to be needed.

Comment: I don't think we are being told everything. Why would the reviewer comment on encapsulation and completely disregard that this is a class with just one public member variable. In his place, I would request for the class to be discarded in favour of just passing the URL string around. If there are other members that are not shown in the sample above, there might be a good enough reason to tighten the encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

The getter function is the counterpart of the setter. With the setter, client code is able to set the value. With the getter, the client code needs to be able to get the value.

I can think of couple of ways to do it.

```
std::string const& get_url() const
{
   return this->url;
}

void get_url(std::string& url) const
{
    url = this->url;
}
```

You are being asked to implement it using the second approach.